# Using named routes in a laravel 5.1 config file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to use a named route in my config file and I keep getting a 500 error.

```
<?php
return [
    'Warden' => [
         route('warden::models', ['user']), 
         'fa fa-btn fa-fw fa-user-secret text-success'
    ],
    'Dispatch' => [
         route('dispatch::index'), 
         'fa fa-btn fa-fw fa-fa-microphone text-success'
    ],
    'Identicon' => [
         route('identicon::main', [md5(Auth::user()->email)]), 
         'fa fa-btn fa-fw fa-get-pocket text-success'
    ]
];
```

I was wondering if there might be something in Laravel that is preventing this from happening. If not, am I doing something improperly?

*Also:* Side note.

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  
   Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct()  must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in 
   /home/austin/html/hidden/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 62 
   and defined in /home/austin/html/hidden/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php on line 99
```

Is the only error I get in my console and that's only when I use `php artisan serve`.

#### Update

I'm no longer at work so I don't have my exact source code with me; however, it was similar to what's below.

(in a blade file) where kregel is a directory and menu is the file name.

```
@foreach(config('kregel.menu') as $menu_item => list($link, $icon))
  <li>
    <a href="{{$link}}>
      $menu_item <i class="{{$icon}}"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: How are you calling those routes? Something like this?: `config('my_config.Warden.0')`.

Comment: I'll update my answer to reflect how I'm calling them.

Comment: Accessing routes is not available when configuration files are bootstrapped. Check your server's (e.g., Apache) logs to see exactly what error is being thrown. It's likely something like "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class log does not exist' in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:737". An error is happening so early in the bootstrap process, it doesn't know how to handle it.

Comment: @SandyandiN.delaCruz I have updated my answer with how I am calling the routes.

Comment: @Cryode has a point.

Comment: @Cryode is there anyway around this? I'm trying to use these routes because it would be easier in case I ever decide to change the name of the order I want these? It's easier to edit a config file than it is to dig through some view or controller.

Comment: Can't you just save the route names in the config file, instead of trying to build the whole URL? Honestly I don't see why adding a config file just to define the order of your menu is going to be any easier than finding the menu template and changing the order. Otherwise you can always just use a simple service class to help you do this. The point is to not expect routing, or almost any other service bound to the IOC container, to work in config files (including the Auth facade).

Comment: Fair point, thank you. I'll work with my code some more and try to work with something else.

Comment: Updated my answer to show my eventual solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have found my solution and figured I would share just for the sake of open source-ness.

So instead of just using the Auth facade or the route method. I instead chose to use a closure for the facade and a string for the route.

Example:

```
'Identicon' => [
   'link' =>[
      'identicon::main', 
      function() {
         return md5(Auth::user()->email);
      }
   ], 
   'icon' => 'fa fa-btn fa-fw fa-get-pocket text-success'
]
```

The actual function I have used to produce and build the link.

```
protected function linkBuilder($link){
    // This makes sure that there is indeed parameters.
    if(!is_array($link)){
        return route($link);
    }

    // This grabs the two expected parameters.
    list($route, $params) = $link;

    // Now we see if the parameter(s) is actually an anon function
    if($params instanceof Closure) {
        // call this function
        return route($route, $params());
    }
    // This must have no function and must just be 
    // either an array of parameters or just a string
    return route($route, $params);
}
```

Now to use this function you would end up passing through the array with the key 'link' to this function. So therefore what ends up getting returned is the proper value.

This means that the resulting route function would actually look like

```
route('identicon::main', md5(Auth::user()->email));
```

Which, while it might be a little messy, works INCREDIBLY well for my task. If there is any other way, anyone might be able to think of to use a  facade or a named route form within my config please let me know.

Comment: What you have is probably the best route if you want to keep using a config file. Otherwise just build your own class that returns this information, and retrieve it via a View Composer. You don't want to use facades and whatnot in your config files, that's not what they're for.